# Increase size limit of SQL Azure database from 50GB to 100GB

Tags: azure-sql-database

Can I increase size limit of an Azure database from 50GB to 100GB? if that's possible, what the implications are for the end users and processes? i.e., is the database set offline while the change is happening?

Will it be done by the following instruction?

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase MODIFY (EDITION='BUSINESS', MAXSIZE=100GB)
```

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the instruction.

The database users/processes should not be impacted by this change from 50GB to 100GB, you are just setting an upper limit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx

states that the max size for Business Edition is 150GB so you should be fine.

Comment: "Changing the edition or maximum size of the database in a synchronous and offline operation and results in existing connections to be disconnected." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394109.aspx